# How to perfrom subnetting for class B private IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, computer-science, subnet, private-ip

Suppose you are assigned to design a LAN for an office having 8 departments. Each department will have 28 computers located in different rooms. Perform subnetting assuming class B private IP address.

Comment: Network address classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet in 1995) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had network address classes in this century, and any course that still teaches it should refund your money. There is a specific section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that covers subnetting, and the very last section covers network address classes.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like homework.

Comment: Network classes haven't been a thing for decades.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using VLAN for each department, you can use this [documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/switches/cisco-small-business-300-series-managed-switches/smb5653-configure-port-to-vlan-interface-settings-on-a-switch-throug.html)
how to configure VLAN network and also you can view here example architecture.

Once the VLAN configured you can now use the Class B IP addresses depending on your network setup, you can also use this [link](https://www.alliedtelesis.com/sites/default/files/ip_address_chart_revf.pdf) IP Address and Subnetting Guide.

Answer (score 0):

The question wants you to understand the Class B allocation of private addressing within RFC1918.  RFC1918 allocated a single class A, 16 class Bs and an entire block of 256 class Cs.  To answer this question (i'm not doing  what is clearly your homework for you) You need to seach for all of the address space set aside in RFC1918 and figure out which is class B.
Then, using some of that address space, create subnets sufficient for networks containing 28 hosts on each network.  I'm not sure if your professor/instructor is expecting you to make subnets that are just big enough to support that many users or if you are expected to allow for a resonable amount of growth.  You might want to clarify.